# MAUI: Relative routing to shell elements is currently not supported

Tags: c#, .net, navigation, maui

I recreated a new app maui and to make the navigation I redid what worked on another app that I made (on the other app it still works). As soon as I navigate on a new page everything goes well but it's as soon as I want to come back on the page where I was or I have a bug.

NavigationService.cs

```
public async Task NavigateAsync(NavigationPages page)
        {

            try
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(page.ToString(), true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand GoBacKCommand { get; }

public ParamViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            GoBacKCommand = new Command(GoBacKExecute);
            this.navigationService = navigationService;
        }
private void GoBacKExecute()
        {
            navigationService.NavigateAsync(BusinessModels.NavigationPages.MainPage);
        }
```

MauiProgram.cs

```
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
        services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
        services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
```

and the Exception  is : **Relative routing to shell elements is currently not supported. Try prefixing your uri with ///: ///MainPage**

but if I do what it says (///MainPage) the navigation does not work anymore

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: could you include more code/xaml in order to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: But when I used the `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");`, it worked well.

Comment: it only works if I do menu to settings then settings to menu but as soon as I do menu to settings then player and I want to return to settings it doesn't work

Comment: How do you navigate to new pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want go back to a page (like PopUp) you need to need use GotoAsync as below

ViewModel.cs

```
  public ICommand Back_Command { get; set; }
  public ViewModel()
  {
        Back_Command = new Command(Back);
  }
  private async void Back()
  {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
  }
```

Page.xaml

```
 <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior 
        Command="{Binding Back_Command}"/>
 </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

Further explanation has been stated in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation

Comment: it work white only one page deep but whit two it do not work